# pixel selection to cut, paste, and move pixels in texture paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Is there any way to select pixels in blender texture paint similar to how in Photoshop you can marquee or lasso pixels to cut, paste, and move them?

I'm working with animating pixel art on sprite sheet textures so I want to be able to cleanly cut and move the pixels without distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Texture paint as of yet doesn't allow actual selection of pixels in any way close to Photoshop or Gimp do. I have several workarounds that I use though to work from camera view on an image plane and then project from view to new geometry that serves as my duplicated pixels/selection. This is a bit of work for a novice, and only works on 2d images and not when painting on a 3d model with a wrapped texture. Many people just keep the image texture open in a separate image editor program and update the image texture in Blender once saved in PS/Gimp/etc.